# how convert integers in a matrix to their corresponding alphabets in python

Tags: python

i am trying to convert a matrix of integers to their corresponding alphabet in python. 
1=a,b=2 etc
this what i have so far where xlabels is the matrix with the integers.

```
a = np.zeros((15,15))
for x in xrange(0,15):
    for y in xrange(0,15):
        a[x, y] = chr(ord('a')-1 + xlabels[0, 0])
print(a)
```

But I get an error saying

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: n
```

Comment: `numpy` arrays are *typed*, unlike the built-in data structures. You can't put strings in an array of numbers. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
a = np.zeros((15,15))
```

with:

```
a = np.zeros((15,15), dtype=str)
```